# Sistema de Registro e Login python

Tags: python, lista

Eu estou tentando desenvolver um simples sistema de registro e login utilizando arquivos de texto, porém na hora de efetuar o login está dando erro.

Creio eu é na variável "Registrados", pois pelo que entendi pelo comando `a.readlines()` ele lê e transforma em uma lista, mas quando verifico se é elemento da lista dá erro....

```
#-*- coding: utf-8
#Registro

a = open("registrados.txt","a")#Abrindo pasta no modo de adcionar novos dados
print("Você selecionou a opção de cadastrar uma nova conta")
nome_usuario = input("Por favor informe o seu nome de usuario: ")
a.write(nome_usuario)
print("Cadastrado com sucesso!")
#login
print("Efetue Login")
nome_login = input("Digite o seu nome de usuario: ")
registrados = a.readlines() # Leu o arquivo e transformou em uma lista chamada registrados
if nome_login in registrados :
    print("Bem vindo, Fulano, ")
else:
    print("Você deve ter digitado seu nome de usuario errado, por favor verifique.")
```

Comment: Pesquise mais sobre o modo de leitura de arquivos. Você utilizou o modo `'a'` para abrir o arquivo, que é um modo de escrita; você não consegue ler o conteúdo quando o arquivo é aberto assim. Seria interessante você trabalhar de forma isolada: no registro você abre para escrita, no login você abre para leitura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se responderei o que deseja, mas tentarei respondê-lo da melhor forma.
Aqui segue o seu algoritmo com algumas modificações

```
arq = open('registrados.txt', 'a')
print('Olá, aqui você pode adicionar uma nova conta!')
nome_usuario = input('Digite o nome de usuário: ')

arq.write('{}\n'.format(nome_usuario))
'''
Adição da constante \n new line
Uma vez que write não o adiciona automaticamente
'''

print('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!\n')
arq.close() #O arquivo é fechado do modo de adição para ser aberto
            #posteriormente no modo de leitura

arq = open('registrados.txt') #abrindo no modo de leitura
print('Efetue o seu login')
nome_login = input('Digite o seu nome de usuario: ')

registrados = arq.readlines()
if nome_login + '\n' in registrados:
    print('Bem vindo, {}!'.format(nome_login))
else:
    print('Você deve ter digitado seu nome de usuario errado, por favor verifique.')
arq.close()
```

Cuidado com as quebras de linha, pois, uma vez que o método readlines reconhece as linhas devido à presença da constante \n ao final de cada linha, esta deve estar devidamente colocada nas linhas do arquivo.

Answer (score -1):

arq = open('registrados.txt', 'a')
print('Olá, aqui você pode adicionar uma nova conta!')
nome_usuario = input('Digite o nome de usuário: ')
senha_usuario = input('Digite a sua senha de usuário: )

arq.write('{} - {}\n'.format(nome_usuario, senha_usuario))
'''
Adição da constante \n new line
Uma vez que write não o adiciona automaticamente
'''

print('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!\n')
arq.close() #O arquivo é fechado do modo de adição para ser aberto
#posteriormente no modo de leitura

arq = open('registrados.txt') #abrindo no modo de leitura
print('Efetue o seu login')
nome_login = input('Digite o seu nome de usuario: ')
senha_login = input('Digite a sua senha de usuário: )

registrados = arq.readlines()
if nome_login + senha_login + '\n' in registrados:
print('Bem vindo, {}!'.format(nome_login))
else:
print('Você deve ter digitado seu nome de usuario errado, por favor verifique.')
arq.close()

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).